# AppBar below keyboard

Tags: textbox, keyboard, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, appbar

How to create appBar like on the picture. It'll be great if the appbar shows only when textbox is focus.[appbar below keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilq8G.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the event GotFocus to show your appbar and LostFocus event to hide or collapse your appbar

GotFocus
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.gotfocus

LostFocus
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.lostfocus

Update : If you want to show your appbar when the textbox is focus you can use IsSticky= True

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.issticky.aspx

With this property your appbar will be visible even with the keyboard visible.
I hope this helps!

Comment: No it doesn't help. The appbar lands above keyboard.

Comment: thanks! but in this solution the appbar lands above keyboard too. On the picture, appbar is below keyboard even when You typing into textbox.

Comment: well that behavior is for Windows Phone 8 or 8.1 for UWP the appbar behavior is different. It is not possible to do the same like Windows phone 8 .